# Entity Framework naming conventions for the same table name across multiple schemas

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, naming-standards

The `DbContext` of my application's Entity Framework setup (which I will refer to as `ApplicationContext`, the name of our derived type) contains classes for all of the tables in our SQL Server database, rather than having them spread out across multiple `DbContext` classes. One of the issues we've run into is, because EF uses reflection to map the entity classes to their table/view counterparts, all of those classes must be in the same namespace as the `ApplicationContext` (if this is incorrect, please let me know).

As a result, when two SQL tables in different schemas share the same name, naming the EF classes becomes a problem.

Let's say I have two tables: `FranchisorSetup.ProposalTextBlocks` and `ProposalManagement.ProposalTextBlocks`. Because of the limitation of EF I mentioned earlier, both of those entity classes must exist in the same namespace if they are to both be a part of `ApplicationContext`.

My EF class definition might look like this:

```
namespace MyApp.DAL.EF
{
    [Table("FranchisorSetup.ProposalTextBlocks")]
    public class ProposalTextBlock { // class definition }
}
```

This works fine for one table, but my second table, `ProposalManagement.ProposalTextBlocks`, *also* needs to be named `ProposalTextBlock`. This will give me a compiler error, as that class name is already being taken by the first table.

Using a different `DbContext` for each schema would solve this particular issue, but create a host of others. What is a standard way of solving this issue?

Comment: I don't think the class name has to match the table name... It can be whatever you want. Like described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184644/howto-specify-table-name-with-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api

Comment: True, which is what I'm using the `[Table]` data annotation for. I could always fudge the names, but the point of my post is to see if there is a best practice for handling this situation without having to do that. In fact, it seems so basic and common that I'm curious as to why I haven't been able to find a standard solution out there

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'm not sure I see why you're hesitant here... The standard solution would be to find a better, unique names for your classes. I was thrown by the "but my second table, ProposalManagement.ProposalTextBlocks, also needs to be named ProposalTextBlock". In reality, *neither* of them need to be named such.

Comment: I get ya. We ended up appending the schema as a prefix to the class names. Ends up being really long, but at least there's no ambiguity.